# function could not match type

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference

I have function as below:

```
    foo :: Int -> a -> [a]
    foo n v = bar n
      where
        bar :: Int -> [a]
        bar n = take n $ repeat v
```

using ghci report this error:

```
    Couldn't match type `a' with `a1'
          `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
              the type signature for foo :: Int -> a -> [a] at hs99.hs:872:1
          `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
              the type signature for bar :: Int -> [a1] at hs99.hs:875:9
    Expected type: [a1]
        Actual type: [a]
    In the expression: take n $ repeat v
    In an equation for `bar': bar n = take n $ repeat v
```

If removing the type declaration of bar, code can be compiled without error. So what's the proper type declaration of bar here? And why error happens, because type declaration of bar is more generic than definition of bar (which is bound to some type in foo)?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `a` in

```
foo :: Int -> a -> [a]
```

and the `a` in

```
    bar :: Int -> [a]
```

are different type variables with the same name.

To get the behaviour you expect, turn on the ScopedTypeVariables extension (e.g. by inserting `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` at the top of your source file), and change the type signature of `foo` to

```
foo :: forall a. Int -> a -> [a]
```

---

When ScopedTypeVariables is not enabled, it is as if your original code was written like this:

```
foo :: forall a. Int -> a -> [a]
foo n v = bar n
  where
    bar :: forall a. Int -> [a]
    bar n = take n $ repeat v
```

It is not true to say that ghci implicitly uses ScopedTypeVariables if you leave out the type annotation for `bar`.

Instead, the type annotation you give for `bar` conflicts with the type ghci infers --- you are asserting `bar` has a type that ghci knows it can't have.

When you remove the type annotation, you remove the conflict.

ScopedTypeVariables changes the meaning of type annotations that you supply. It does not effect how ghc infers types.

Comment: Thanks for help! As I said, if removing type declaration of 'bar', ghci can compile the code, does that mean ghci implicitly using ScopedTypeVariable here for it?

Comment: be more clear, scoped type variables and removing 'bar' type declaration both can make the code compiled. just wondering if they are doing the same trick.

Comment: No, they get to the same compiled code, but they get there differently. See my edit.

Comment: Then if without scoped type variables, can we declare type of bar as what ghci infers?

Answer (score 2):

And just found this thread has a good explanation as well: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2008-June/044617.html